# trigger a collection view cell to recalculate size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that has 4 cell each corresponds to a childViewController! When pressing on a certain button inside of one of the children the height of that child change and I am capturing this change through those methods in the childVC

```
extension SearchBaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        calculatePreferredSize()
    }

    private func calculatePreferredSize() {
        preferredContentSize = cardView.frame.size
    }
}
```

and trying to capture the height so the collectionView use that height when caluculating the cell height in the parentVC

```
override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {
        super.preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer: container)
        if (container as? SearchFlightViewController) != nil {
            flightCardHeight = container.preferredContentSize.height
        } else if (container as? SearchHotelViewController) != nil {
            hotelCardHeight = container.preferredContentSize.height
        } else if (container as? BlackCarSearchFormVC) != nil {
            blackCarCardHeight = container.preferredContentSize.height
        } else if (container as? SearchCarViewController) != nil {
            rentalCarCardHeight = container.preferredContentSize.height
        } else if (container as? SearchRailVC) != nil || (container as? SearchRailViewController) != nil {
            railCardHeight = container.preferredContentSize.height
        }
        collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        updatePersonalSwitchConstraints()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Now those 3 line of codes

```
collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
updatePersonalSwitchConstraints()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

doesnt force the collectionView to call this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

How can I trigger the recalculation? Notice that I do not wont to reload the cell nor I wanna call collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidate() because this method mess up all my UI...

Any ideas?